# Thousands of nodes in Cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I have a graph with 30.000 nodes and 24.000 edges approximately. Using `cytoscape.js`, the browser never finishes loadind data... When trying a graph with 1.500 nodes and 1.700 edges, everything's OK.

So, I know the problem is the number of nodes/edges to load. How can I deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have trouble rendering graphs of that size using any library.  You can load all of the elements into the graph, but you should only draw a subset for performance.  You can do this by hiding elements in the stylesheet : http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/visibility